# python weasyprint OSError bad path

Tags: python-3.x, weasyprint

The issue I am running into when attempting to create a pdf from weasyprint using the following code

```
from weasyprint import HTML
string_html = create_string_html()  # over simplified for question. It is created from a jinja template

HTML(string_html).write_pdf('example.pdf')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\...\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 112, in __init__
    with result as (source_type, source, base_url, protocol_encoding):
  File "C:\...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\...\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 396, in _select_source
    with result as result:
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\...\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 402, in _select_source
    base_url = path2url(filename)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\urls.py", line 98, in path2url
    path = pathname2url(path)
  File "C:\...\nturl2path.py", line 65, in pathname2url
    raise OSError(error)
OSError: Bad path: C:\...\<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is `weasyprint`'s `HTML` function's first argument was looking for a file location. In order to pass a string make the string a named variable like so:

```
HTML(string=string_html).write_pdf('example.pdf')
```

More information can be found here: [Instantiating HTML and CSS objects](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#instantiating-html-and-css-objects)

Answer (score 0):

As written in weasyprint doc:

```
from weasyprint import HTML

HTML('../foo.html')  # Same as …
HTML(filename='../foo.html')
```

So you can't pass a string this way, you have to explicit declare that you're going to give him a string, notice that's the same for the CSS obj.

```
from weasyprint import HTML

HTML(string='''
    <h1>The title</h1>
    <p>Content goes here
''')

CSS(string='@page { size: A3; margin: 1cm }') # Passing strings instead paths
```

Hope it helps.
Hele.